# Can pattern matching be applied to a generic type parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, pattern-matching

Let's say I have this code like this....

```
public void SayType<T,E>(Func<T, E> f)
{

    var dataType = string.Empty;
    if (typeof(E) == typeof(DateTime))
        dataType = "date/time";
    else if (typeof(E) == typeof(string)) 
        dataType = "text";
    else if (typeof(E) == typeof(int)) 
        dataType = "whole number";
   
    Console.WriteLine($"type identified as {dataType}");
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite this with pattern-matching?  E.g. something like:

```
 //Note this won't compile since the LHS of a case must be a const.
 var dataType = typeof(E) switch {
      typeof(DateTime) => "date/time",
      typeof(string) => "text",
      typeof(int) => "whole number",
 };
```

[This github proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-7.1/generics-pattern-match.md) may be relevant but I could just be reading too much into it.

Comment: Since generic type parameters are resolved at compile time, you could just as well overload the methods: `public void SayType<T>(Func<T, DateTime> f)`, `public void SayType<T>(Func<T, string> f)` and `public void SayType<T>(Func<T, int> f)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` requires an instance which will be [type-tested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) so it will not be useful here. You can try a bit hackish approach with case guards:

```cs
var type = typeof(E);
var dataType = true switch
{
    _ when type == typeof(DateTime) => "date/time",
    _ when type == typeof(string) => "text",
    // ....
    _ => string.Empty
};
```

But it can be considered too hackish due to the tested value being ignored in the switch expression arms.

Comment: I didn't understand your last sentence.

Comment: @RobertHarvey in `true switch` `true` is ignored (not tested/checked) by switch cases .

Comment: @RobertHarvey `var type = typeof(E);`

Comment: I'd like a bit more information about why you consider this hackish.  Is there any peril here, other than it being a bit obtuse?

Comment: @RobertHarvey cause it breaks the original intent of the `switch` expression - to pattern match with the input expression. Again, personally I'm actually fine with such usage but I see the validity in argument this being not the cleanest code.

Comment: Thanks Guru - fwiw agree on the slight "hackish" element of having to encode the type in the condition but still an improvement over the nested if/then I think.  Another imperfect approach is to just use a lookup table of course.. debatable which is clearer..